# How to create a Reference Assembly with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-assembly

I'm trying to create a Reference Assembly with Visual Studio 2017 and not with the command line.

I've created a new class library project using Visual Studio 2017 and I've modified the constructor of the default class like this:

```
using System;

namespace ReferenceAssembly
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            throw new Exception("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

As I want a reference assembly, I hope the constructor's implementation like `throw null` and not `throw new Exception("Hello World");`

If I compile the project from the command line:

```
csc.exe /target:library /refonly /out:referenceAssembly.dll Class1.cs
```

...everything works fine: if I decompile the assembly what I get is as expected:

```
public Class1()
{
    throw null;
}
```

Now I want to do it via Visual Studio 2017.

Visual Studio 2017 c# property window doesn't have any flag to specify the *refonly* flag, so I decided to edit the .csproj file adding `<ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>` inside each PropertyGroup node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>3be579e4-9fde-4fd1-867c-ac5cd0411b65</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ReferenceAssembly</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ReferenceAssembly</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Core"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions"/>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Data"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
 </Project>
```

But after compiling with Visual Studio 2017 what I get after decompiling is:

```
public Class1()
{
    throw new Exception("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Which VS version?

Comment: 2017. I'm going to edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to create a Reference Assembly with Visual Studio

**Workaround:**

Try using `ProduceReferenceAssembly` when you're in VS2017. Then you can find the reference assembly in `ref` folder. (Or you can use VS2019, this issue is fixed there.)

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2017), `ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly` is a boolean value that instructs the compiler to emit only a reference assembly rather than compiled code. This property **corresponds to** the `/refonly` switch of the `vbc.exe and csc.exe` compilers.

It's strange that the `ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly` failed to work in VS while the command-line worked. I think it could be one issue with VS2017, so I suggest you report this one to [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

(I test the property  and find it works well in VS2019).